# Limit randomized element from array to be displayed in image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have created an array of images that will be randomized and 2 randomly generated images will be displayed in the 2 image tags created in my HTML body. Each of the randomized images will only be displayed once.

**Issue:**

However, I am facing a roadblock at this point. I am trying to limit an individual element in the array to be randomized to a maximum of `n` times.

Meaning:

```
Array_A = [A, B, C, D, E]
```

I have randomized  `Array_A` and the randomly generated images will be displayed in my two `<img>` within my HTML body. Hence, when I do a `console.log`, two elements from `Array_A` will be displayed.

However, I am thinking of limiting e.g: element `C` in `Array_A` to be displayed 5 times, meaning, the randomized count for `index = 2` is only 5, if the count is more than 5, then the random method is called again to get another randomized element.

I have searched the net for any reference but came up none.

```js
var Brand_list = [];

 var BrandNameArray = ["lib/img/Brands/A.png", "lib/img/Brands/B.png", "lib/img/Brands/C.png", "lib/img/Brands/D.png", "lib/img/Brands/E.png"];

 //Randomised Brand Offer
 //Auto populate into brand container once randomised
 $('#BrandWinlist > img').each(function(i, img) {
   var flag = false;
   do {
     random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
     if (Brand_list.indexOf(random_BrandIndex) == -1) {
       flag = true;
       Brand_list.push(random_BrandIndex);
       console.log("random_BrandIndex:" + random_BrandIndex);
       var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
       $(img).attr('src', Brand).attr("alt", Brand).show();
     }
   } while (!flag);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="GameWinBrand_Container">
  <div id="BrandWinlist" class="GameWinBrand_innerScroll">
    <img id="GameBrand_1" style="width:230px; height:230px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" onclick="selectBrand('1');">
    <img id="GameBrand_2" style="width:230px; height:230px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('2');">
  </div>
</div>
```

Therefore, is there any way that I am able to limit a randomized element to be displayed a stated number of times?

Comment: will the page be refreshed/document be reloaded when images are 'redisplayed'? ie. is this something that needs to stored with a cookie/localstorage?

Comment: @haxxxton, nope, the page will not refresh/ document be reloaded when images are re-displayed, it will have to display the next available randomised image. I assume that the count needs to be keep tracked of.

Comment: If display count reaches 5 then delete that image from the array (`images.splice(i,1)`) and carry on with your normal random image select operation.

Comment: @Redu Do you have an example? i would assume "i" is the name of the element? If that is the case, how do you reference the name of the element within the array?

Comment: @Luke `i` is the index of the image element to delete from the images array. I will post an answer later today once i am free... But as for now i can say that you can keep a `displayCount` property within the images array items. Each item can be an object to hold the `displayCount` and `image` properties.

Comment: @Redu, so display count will be a variable and that i will just need to reference a single index of the element to be deleted to the displayCount property?

Answer (score 1):

Following is an example to get random elements from a given array.

#### Logic

1. Create a copy of original array, so that you do not override original array.
2. Get random number, and convert it into int. To ensure its in the range, you should use `%` on length of dummy array.
3. Now that you have random index in correct range, push this element in result array
4. Now decrement count, if exists. If count is equal to `0`, remove it from dummy array. This will ensure, elements are not repeated after given number of time.

Now you have a list of image names that are random and unique. Return it and then loop over them and update tags.

#### Sample

```js
var BrandNameArray = [{src: "lib/img/Brands/A.png", maxCount:2},
                      {src: "lib/img/Brands/B.png"},
                      {src: "lib/img/Brands/C.png", maxCount:1},
                      {src: "lib/img/Brands/D.png"},
                      {src: "lib/img/Brands/E.png"}];

function getRandomList(arr, len, maxRepeat) {
  // To store result
  var _r = []

  // To ensure original array is not updated
  var _a = arr.slice(0);

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // get random number and find index using % to ensure index is in range
    var _index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) % _a.length;
    _r.push(_a[_index].src);
    if (_a[_index].hasOwnProperty("maxCount") && --_a[_index].maxCount <=0) {
      // remove added element from temp array.
      _a.splice(_index, 1);
    }
  }
  return _r
}

console.log(getRandomList(BrandNameArray, 8))
console.log(getRandomList(BrandNameArray, 5))
```

Comment: I don't think you get the issue of my question. The solution that you have provided is only to get unique item from an array of element. I have managed to achieve that. However, the issue that i am facing is this: I want to limit "lib/img/Brands/A.png" to be able to be randomised and display only 5 times, after the 5th time, "A.png" will not be randomised to be on display again. Or am I not understanding you?

Comment: How do you determine a specific element, for e.g: element "D.png" to be the index that is to be removed after 5 counts of the element being displayed after being randomised?

Comment: I think I still do not fully understand your problem. So this is what I understand. You have array of images and which are to be displayed in random order. Now every image can be repeated `x` times. After this it should not appear but other images can appear randomly. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I have an array of images. The images in the array can be randomised and be displayed indefinite time except for one image in the array, can only be randomised and be displayed `x` times. After that, it should not be randomised and appear but other images can still appear randomly

Comment: @Luke I have updated the answer. Note I have taken leisure to update your array. Hope that is a feasible option.

Answer (score 0):

Please read my comments to understand the logic.

```js
var Brand_list = [];

 var BrandNameArray = ["lib/img/Brands/A.png", "lib/img/Brands/B.png", "lib/img/Brands/C.png", "lib/img/Brands/D.png", "lib/img/Brands/E.png"];

 var limit = 2;  //this is where you will set limit of the image to appear randomly
 var limitImageAtIndex = 0; //here you define Index of image that has to be limited, i have set to zero it means first image is limited to be appear 2 times

 setTimeout(randomize,1000);

 function randomize(){
   //Randomized Brand Offer
 //Auto populate into brand container once randomized
 $('#BrandWinlist > img').each(function(i, img) {
   var flag = false;
   do {
     random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);

       //here is the logic to limit the image
       //if (Brand_list.indexOf(random_BrandIndex) == -1) {

       if(limitImageAtIndex == random_BrandIndex){
          limit--; 
          if(limit<0){
               continue; //continue to next iteration skip this image
          }
       }
       ///////////////
  
       flag = true;
       Brand_list.push(random_BrandIndex);
       console.log("random_BrandIndex:" + random_BrandIndex);
       var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
       $(img).attr('src', Brand).attr("alt", Brand).show();
     //}
   } while (!flag);
  });
  setTimeout(randomize,2000);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="GameWinBrand_Container">
  <div id="BrandWinlist" class="GameWinBrand_innerScroll">
    <img id="GameBrand_1" style="width:230px; height:230px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" onclick="selectBrand('1');">
    <img id="GameBrand_2" style="width:230px; height:230px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('2');">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am still able to return the value to exceed more than the limit set for the index in the array

Comment: where is your code that automate these images (like setTimeOut func)

Comment: @Luke are you there?

Comment: Hey @Luke, TRY MY CODE AGAIN hit Run code snippet and see the output for yourself and  let me know if you need some explanation.

Comment: well, when i run your code, the image index "0" is displayed more than twice. I think i do understand your solution though

Comment: but its working on my side perfectly 0 appearing only twice, maybe you need to clear cache, try on other browser

Comment: let me try to run it again

Comment: I have tried it  but have observed this behaviour, the current behaviour that i am facing: have done a console.log(limit) and i could see the value decrease for only just once, before, it stops counting and deducting the value. It is occurring for both index [A, B]. I could see from here, that the code is rightfully working though. Would just like to confirm, will the count stop if the page refreshes?

Comment: which count you are talking about I don't get your point? but if you are talking about the limit count then yes it will restart again after page refresh, means if you have restricted A to 2 times then it will show only 2times whenever you refresh page.

Comment: for that purpose you'll need cookies I think

Comment: no wonder!! cause everytime the page refreshes. The console.log of limit is always stuck at 1, after the initial the `limit--`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do something like the following snippet. It will display two random images per mouse click on the container div. The images have a quota designated by `displayLimit` (currently all set to 5). You can test the code at [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FHNMLe0K8xSOQ28EkYbl?p=preview).

```js
function selectBrand(e){
  var newImages;
  if (images.length < 6) {
  for (var oldImage of oldImages) { oldImage.displayCount < oldImage.displayLimit && images.push(oldImage)};
    oldImages = [];
  }
  newImages = images.length >= 2 ? Array(2).fill()
                                           .map(e => {var image = images.splice(~~(Math.random()*images.length),1)[0];
                                                      image.displayCount++;
                                                      return image})
                                 : imagesOnDisplay;
  newImages.forEach((image,i) => imageElements[i].src = image.src);
  oldImages = imagesOnDisplay.slice();
  imagesOnDisplay = newImages.slice();
}

var BrandNameArray = ["http://www.sonus-festival.com/e276/e975/e564/photo1773/250-MG_0222_eng.jpg",
                      "http://www.sonus-festival.com/e276/e975/e564/photo1790/250-KIDKUTSMEDIA-4524_eng.jpg",
                      "http://mlampros.github.io/images/11st.jpeg",
                      "http://oneeyeland.com/awards/images/thumb/2015/194652.jpg",
                      "http://oneeyeland.com/awards/images/thumb/2015/195491.jpg",
                      "http://oneeyeland.com/awards/images/thumb/2015/195821.jpg",
                      "http://oneeyeland.com/awards/images/thumb/2015/197506.jpg",
                      "http://oneeyeland.com/250/218410-one-eyeland-fenna-2-by-gemmy-woud-binnendijk.jpg"],
            limits = [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
            images = BrandNameArray.map((e,i) => ({         src: e,
                                                   displayCount: 0,
                                                   displayLimit: limits[i]
                                                 })),
         oldImages = [],
   imagesOnDisplay = Array(2).fill().map(e => images.splice(~~(Math.random()*images.length),1)[0]),
         imagesDiv = document.getElementById("BrandWinlist"),
     imageElements = imagesDiv.querySelectorAll("img");
     
imagesOnDisplay.forEach((image,i) => imageElements[i].src = image.src);
imagesDiv.addEventListener("click", selectBrand);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="GameWinBrand_Container">
    <div id="BrandWinlist" class="GameWinBrand_innerScroll">
      <img id="GameBrand_1" style="width:250px; height:250px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px">
      <img id="GameBrand_2" style="width:250px; height:250px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```